# Data Subtractions From Two Mysql Tables Problem

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Products table

| id | item_code | item_name dept | date_received | quantity_received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ELM001 | Jelly ICT | 2021-12-16 | 20 |
| 2 | ELM001 | Jelly ICT | 2021-11-23 | 10 |
| 3 | MVT001 | CARB MVT | 2021-09-17 | 15 |
| 4 | HBT001 | DISK HBT | 2021-08-25 | 12 |
| 5 | MVT001 | CARB MVT | 2020-12-12 | 10 |

issue_products

| id | item_code | date_issued | issued_to | quantity_issued |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ELM001 | 2021-12-17 | John | 12 |
| 1 | MVT001 | 2021-12-16 | Dave | 10 |

expected results

available_products

| item_code | item_name | dept | quantity_received | quantity_issued balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ELM001 | Jelly | ICT | 30 | 12 |
| HBT001 | DISK | HBT | 12 | 0 |
| MVT001 | CARB | MVT 25 | 10 | 15 |

My code

```
SELECT
                item_code,
                item_name,
                dept,
                sum(total1) as quantity_received,
                sum(total2) as quantity_issued,
              SUM(total1) - SUM(total2) AS balance
            FROM (SELECT id, item_code,
           cons_received AS total1, 0 AS total2
            FROM Products_table
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id,item_code,
              0 AS total1, cons_issued AS total2
      FROM issue_products) a   GROUP BY item_code
```

am getting error

unknown columns

Comment: Your subquery does have columns `item_name` and `dept` in its output list. You must add these columns to output lists of both subqueries in UNION, or join a table which contains this data.

Comment: That is where am Stuck

Comment: Add `item_name` and `dept` into 1st subquery, and NULL for them into 2nd subquery. Use MAX() over these columns in outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT item_code,
       MAX(item_name) item_name,
       MAX(dept) dept,
       sum(total1) as quantity_received,
       sum(total2) as quantity_issued,
       SUM(total1) - SUM(total2) AS balance
FROM ( SELECT id, item_code, cons_received AS total1, 0 AS total2, item_name, dept
       FROM Products_table
     UNION ALL
       SELECT id, item_code, 0, cons_issued, NULL, NULL
       FROM issue_products) a   
GROUP BY item_code;
```

Comment: Small Issue When YOU introduce where example WHERE dept ='ELM001'; quantity issued display 0.